# What is the (commentary) source for Buddha's daily schedule?

Tags: reference-request, sutras, buddha, commentary

What is the (commentary) source for Buddha's five-part daily schedule, as mentioned at [The Buddha's Daily Routine](http://www.buddhanet.net/e-learning/buddhism/lifebuddha/26lbud.htm) (Buddhanet) and [A Day in the Life of the Buddha](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7J17nzlmPnE) (YouTube video, Bhikkhu Bodhi).

Answer (score 4):

We can find mentions of morning, midday or noon and afternoon in [AN 3.19](https://suttacentral.net/an3.19/en/sujato).

> In the same way, a mendicant who has three factors is unable to
> acquire more skillful qualities or to increase the skillful qualities
> they’ve already acquired. What three? It’s when a mendicant doesn’t
> carefully apply themselves to a meditation subject as a foundation of
> immersion in the **morning, at midday, and in the afternoon**.
> [AN 3.19](https://suttacentral.net/an3.19/en/sujato)

For the three watches of the night, we can find it in [MN 53](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.053.than.html). The parts in square brackets are comments from the translator.

> "And how is the disciple of the noble ones devoted to wakefulness?
> There is the case where a disciple of the noble ones, sitting & pacing
> back & forth, cleanses his mind of any qualities that would hold the
> mind in check. During the **first watch of the night** [dusk to 10
> p.m.], sitting & pacing back & forth, he cleanses his mind of any
> qualities that would hold the mind in check. During the **second watch
> of the night** [10 p.m. to 2 a.m.], reclining on his right side, he
> takes up the lion's posture, one foot placed on top of the other,
> mindful, alert, with his mind set on getting up [either as soon as he
> awakens or at a particular time]. During the **last watch of the
> night** [2 a.m. to dawn], sitting & pacing back & forth, he cleanses
> his mind of any qualities that would hold the mind in check. This is
> how the monk is devoted to wakefulness.
> [MN 53](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.053.than.html)

Answer (score 1):

It's from Tipitaka like ruben2020 answered.

The commentary teachers are the Tipitaka Memorizer, so they concluded the [Buddha's normal daily schedule](https://5000y.men/?rm.r.67.45.0.4.) like below...

sīlakkhandhavagga,aṭṭhakathā 45 paṇṇe

> sātthakaṃyeva pana bhagavato kiccaṃ hoti. taṃ pañcavidhaṃ –
> purebhattakiccaṃ, pacchābhattakiccaṃ, purimayāmakiccaṃ,
> majjhimayāmakiccaṃ, pacchimayāmakiccanti.
>
> tatridaṃ purebhattakiccaṃ –
>
> bhagavā hi pātova uṭṭhāya upaṭṭhākānuggahatthaṃ sarīraphāsukatthañca
> mukhadhovanādisarīraparikammaṃ katvā yāva bhikkhācāravelā tāva
> vivittāsane vītināmetvā, bhikkhācāravelāyaṃ nivāsetvā kāyabandhanaṃ
> bandhitvā cīvaraṃ pārupitvā pattamādāya kadāci ekako, kadāci
> bhikkhusaṅghaparivuto, gāmaṃ vā nigamaṃ vā piṇḍāya pavisati; kadāci
> pakatiyā, kadāci anekehi pāṭihāriyehi vattamānehi. seyyathidaṃ,
> piṇḍāya pavisato lokanāthassa purato purato gantvā mudugatavātā
> pathaviṃ sodhenti, valāhakā udakaphusitāni muñcantā magge reṇuṃ
> vūpasametvā upari vitānaṃ hutvā tiṭṭhanti, apare vātā pupphāni
> upasaṃharitvā magge okiranti, unnatā bhūmippadesā onamanti, onatā
> unnamanti, pādanikkhepasamaye samāva bhūmi hoti, sukhasamphassāni
> padumapupphāni vā pāde sampaṭicchanti. indakhīlassa anto ṭhapitamatte
> dakkhiṇapāde sarīrato chabbaṇṇarasmiyo nikkhamitvā
> suvaṇṇarasapiñjarāni viya citrapaṭaparikkhittāni viya ca
> pāsādakūṭāgārādīni alaṅkarontiyo ito cito ca dhāvanti,
> hatthiassavihaṅgādayo sakasakaṭṭhānesu ṭhitāyeva madhurenākārena
> saddaṃ karonti, tathā bherivīṇādīni tūriyāni manussānañca kāyūpagāni
> ābharaṇāni. tena saññāṇena manussā jānanti – ‘‘ajja bhagavā idha
> piṇḍāya paviṭṭho’’ti. te sunivatthā supārutā gandhapupphādīni ādāya
> gharā nikkhamitvā antaravīthiṃ paṭipajjitvā bhagavantaṃ
> gandhapupphādīhi sakkaccaṃ pūjetvā vanditvā – ‘‘amhākaṃ, bhante, dasa
> bhikkhū, amhākaṃ vīsati, paññāsaṃ…pe.… sataṃ dethā’’ti yācitvā
> bhagavatopi pattaṃ gahetvā āsanaṃ paññapetvā sakkaccaṃ piṇḍapātena
> paṭimānenti. bhagavā katabhattakicco tesaṃ sattānaṃ cittasantānāni
> oloketvā tathā dhammaṃ deseti, yathā keci saraṇagamanesu
> patiṭṭhahanti, keci pañcasu sīlesu, keci
> sotāpattisakadāgāmianāgāmiphalānaṃ aññatarasmiṃ; keci pabbajitvā
> aggaphale arahatteti. evaṃ mahājanaṃ anuggahetvā uṭṭhāyāsanā vihāraṃ
> gacchati.
>
> tattha gantvā maṇḍalamāḷe paññattavarabuddhāsane nisīdati, bhikkhūnaṃ
> bhattakiccapariyosānaṃ āgamayamāno. tato bhikkhūnaṃ
> bhattakiccapariyosāne upaṭṭhāko bhagavato nivedeti. atha bhagavā
> gandhakuṭiṃ pavisati. idaṃ tāva purebhattakiccaṃ.
>
> atha bhagavā evaṃ katapurebhattakicco gandhakuṭiyā upaṭṭhāne nisīditvā
> pāde pakkhāletvā pādapīṭhe ṭhatvā bhikkhusaṅghaṃ ovadati –
> ‘‘bhikkhave, appamādena sampādetha, dullabho buddhuppādo lokasmiṃ,
> dullabho manussattapaṭilābho, dullabhā sampatti, dullabhā pabbajjā,
> dullabhaṃ saddhammassavana’’nti. tattha keci bhagavantaṃ kammaṭṭhānaṃ
> pucchanti. bhagavāpi tesaṃ cariyānurūpaṃ kammaṭṭhānaṃ deti. tato
> sabbepi bhagavantaṃ vanditvā attano attano rattiṭṭhānadivāṭṭhānāni
> gacchanti. keci araññaṃ, keci rukkhamūlaṃ, keci pabbatādīnaṃ
> aññataraṃ, keci cātumahārājikabhavanaṃ…pe.… keci vasavattibhavananti.
> tato bhagavā gandhakuṭiṃ pavisitvā sace ākaṅkhati, dakkhiṇena passena
> sato sampajāno muhuttaṃ sīhaseyyaṃ kappeti. atha samassāsitakāyo
> vuṭṭhahitvā dutiyabhāge lokaṃ voloketi. tatiyabhāge yaṃ gāmaṃ vā
> nigamaṃ vā upanissāya viharati tattha mahājano purebhattaṃ dānaṃ datvā
> pacchābhattaṃ sunivattho supāruto gandhapupphādīni ādāya vihāre
> sannipatati. tato bhagavā sampattaparisāya anurūpena pāṭihāriyena
> gantvā dhammasabhāyaṃ paññattavarabuddhāsane nisajja dhammaṃ deseti
> kālayuttaṃ samayayuttaṃ, atha kālaṃ viditvā parisaṃ uyyojeti, manussā
> bhagavantaṃ vanditvā pakkamanti. idaṃ pacchābhattakiccaṃ.
>
> so evaṃ niṭṭhitapacchābhattakicco sace gattāni osiñcitukāmo hoti,
> buddhāsanā vuṭṭhāya nhānakoṭṭhakaṃ pavisitvā upaṭṭhākena
> paṭiyāditaudakena gattāni utuṃ gaṇhāpeti. upaṭṭhākopi buddhāsanaṃ
> ānetvā gandhakuṭipariveṇe paññapeti. bhagavā surattadupaṭṭaṃ nivāsetvā
> kāyabandhanaṃ bandhitvā uttarāsaṅgaṃ ekaṃsaṃ karitvā tattha gantvā
> nisīdati ekakova muhuttaṃ paṭisallīno, atha bhikkhū tato tato āgamma
> bhagavato upaṭṭhānaṃ āgacchanti.
>
> tattha ekacce pañhaṃ pucchanti, ekacce kammaṭṭhānaṃ, ekacce
> dhammassavanaṃ yācanti. bhagavā tesaṃ adhippāyaṃ sampādento
> purimayāmaṃ vītināmeti. idaṃ purimayāmakiccaṃ.
>
> purimayāmakiccapariyosāne pana bhikkhūsu bhagavantaṃ vanditvā
> pakkantesu sakaladasasahassilokadhātudevatāyo okāsaṃ labhamānā
> bhagavantaṃ upasaṅkamitvā pañhaṃ pucchanti, yathābhisaṅkhataṃ antamaso
> caturakkharampi. bhagavā tāsaṃ devatānaṃ pañhaṃ vissajjento
> majjhimayāmaṃ vītināmeti. idaṃ majjhimayāmakiccaṃ.
>
> pacchimayāmaṃ pana tayo koṭṭhāse katvā purebhattato paṭṭhāya nisajjāya
> pīḷitassa sarīrassa kilāsubhāvamocanatthaṃ ekaṃ koṭṭhāsaṃ caṅkamena
> vītināmeti. dutiyakoṭṭhāse gandhakuṭiṃ pavisitvā dakkhiṇena passena
> sato sampajāno sīhaseyyaṃ kappeti. tatiyakoṭṭhāse paccuṭṭhāya
> nisīditvā purimabuddhānaṃ santike dānasīlādivasena
> katādhikārapuggaladassanatthaṃ buddhacakkhunā lokaṃ voloketi. idaṃ
> pacchimayāmakiccaṃ.

Comment: There aren't many people that could translate this. Maybe you could include an English translation?

Comment: Yes, this recovering dumbed down American would like a translation too please, although this is not an official request, as we're all so busy. Also, what are ways to site this? Something like: Sutta Piṭaka Dīghanikāyo sīlakkhandhavagga, aṭṭhakathā 45 paṇṇe?